# Encountering errors while trying to import node modules in Vue 3 (I'm not using typescript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, katex

I've installed `KaTeX` using the command `npm install katex` in my vue3 project.

However, when I try to import the katex module using the following code `import katex from 'katex'` inside my scripts section, vscode shows this error **:**

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'katex'. 'c:/Users/User/Documents/vue/addsub/math/node_modules/katex/dist/katex.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/katex` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'katex';`Vetur(7016)
Could not find a declaration file for module 'katex'. 'C:/Users/User/Documents/vue/addsub/math/node_modules/katex/dist/katex.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/katex` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'katex';`ts(7016)
```

Can someone help me understand what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When a module is not yours - try to install types from @types:

```
npm install -D @types/module-name
```

If the above install errors - try changing import statements to require:

```
// import * as yourModuleName from 'module-name';
const yourModuleName = require('module-name');
```